# Why my php code cannot connect to remote sybase database in apache, centos 7.3, but can connect in console?

Tags: php, database, apache

I'm a php newbie and trying to build a simple website. My developing environment is: CentOS 7.3, Apache 2.4.33, PHP 7.2.6, and database is SAP Sybase IQ 16. The database extension library is built by myself and I set it be auto loaded in php.ini. Then I wrote a test.php as following:

```
$conn = sasql_connect( "UID=DBA;PWD=sql" );
#$conn = sasql_connect( 'Eng=TestDB;Dbn=TestDB;UID=DBA;PWD=sql;CommLinks=tcpip(host=192.168.101.127;port=8888)' );
if( $conn ) {
    echo "Connected successfully\n";
    $result =sasql_query($conn, 'select * from Users');

    while($row = sasql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        echo $row[3];
        echo "\n";
    }

    sasql_free_result($result);
    sasql_disconnect( $conn );
} else {
    echo "Connection failed\n";
}
```

The first two lines in the code is two different connection strings, the first one is used to connect a local database, and the second one is used to connect a remote database. I ran the code via console command: php test.php, I can connect to the both two databases successfully and get correct results. But when I put the test.php in apache and visited it via browser, I found that I can connect to local database successfully but I cannot connect to the remote database, when I tried to do that the browser didn't response and I must restart apache otherwise it wouldn't response any request. 
I checked the error and access log of apache, there wasn't any message. I also checked selinux and firewall, they were both closed. Could you give me any suggestion? Many thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: _Just a thought_ Does your web sites PHP get its `php.ini` file from somewhere different to the PHP CLI?

Comment: You should run `phpinfo();` and make sure everything is loaded as expected.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I confirm that my web sites PHP use the same php.ini as CLI.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, I ran phpinfo(); and I think the sqlanywhere extension library which I use to connect database is loaded. What else should I check?